# how to execute BringIndexIntoViewPublic method of VirtualizingPanel of datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5, virtualization

I am trying to get the object of `VirtualizingPanel` of WPF `DataGrid` and want to execute the method `BringIndexIntoViewPublic`

But I never found any code on net how to call this?

Please let me know, if anyone has any idea how to access the VirtualizingPanel object of DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

After a long RnD. I found the solution :-)

```
        var selector = sender as MultiSelector;

        //// with this way you can call the scrolling item into view even if the items are virtualized.
        //// works only for VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" not for recycle mode.
        var itemsHost = typeof(MultiSelector).InvokeMember("ItemsHost", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance, null, selector, null);

        VirtualizingPanel virtualPanel = itemsHost as VirtualizingPanel;
        if (virtualPanel != null && selector.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            virtualPanel.BringIndexIntoViewPublic(selector.SelectedIndex);
        }
```